# What is the top JavaScript chart library that is free to use in a commercial webapp?

Tags: library, javascript, charts

I am working in site that generates Code ([chart builder](http://charts.livegap.com)) for charts. It's currently working with the [chartnew.js](https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js/) library, but I want to extend with a better chart library.

Requirements:

- Multiple chart types (preferably also 3D charts)
- Charts should be interactive
- Animated graphics
- Free
- License that permits commercial use

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be quite a number of charting libraries for JavaScript that would probably suit your needs. There was also a [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119969/javascript-chart-library) question dealing with this very topic.

[Bonzai](http://bonsaijs.org/) seems to be a good one. It allows for some pretty nice looking 3D charts (as well as interactive), the [documentation](http://docs.bonsaijs.org/) seems to be quite good, and it even features an [editor](http://orbit.bonsaijs.org/#new%20Rect(100%2C%20100%2C%20100%2C%20100).fill(%22red%22).addTo(stage)%3B) online. I can't talk as to how easy it is to use, as I haven't gotten the chance to use it, but from what i've seen, it's quite simple.

[D3](http://d3js.org/) is probably the biggest charting library for JS. It features a lot of variations for charts (a rough count in the Gallery is well over 100). It does have a bit of a learning curve, and all the images are dealt with in SVG format.

Finally, [Rickshaw](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/) is a charting library that tries to simplify D3, at the cost of features (instead of 100 charts, it's at about 10).

Hopefully one of these work out for you! Let me know if they do, and if not, I could probably find more.

Comment: It might be worth a re-read of [the "how to answer" FAQ](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/353)

Comment: Please give a few examples of multiple chart types (preferably also 3D charts) that are interactive, with animated graphics. Screenshots would be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Essential Chart for JavaScript can meet your requirements.

- Supports multiple chart types including 3D

  http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/chart/line
- Supports interaction using events and also built in zooming, panning and interactive cursors
- The SVG rendering mode supports animations
- The community license is free and allows for use in commercial applications.

  http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Please give a few examples of multiple chart types (preferably also 3D charts) that are interactive, with animated graphics. Screenshots would be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [JIT](http://thejit.org/) (Javascript InfoVis Toolkit) is another library you may want to consider, mentioned in my answer at [Open source javascript libraries for generating process flow diagrams](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18599) also.

**Note**: the question here is clearly about **Charts**, like the libraries (charting engines) mentioned in the [Comparison of charting modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985#supportedlibraries), not to be confused with **Graphs**, as mentioned in the [Graphing modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/1389294). Even though both links are related to [drupal](/questions/tagged/drupal) "modules" (which are like plugins), these linked page contains lots of links to 'libraries' (engines for charting or graphing).

PS: the question contains "*... a better chart library ...*", consider editing your question a bit to explain why that word is included, i.e. what kind of issue are you facing with the current library that you'd want to be addressed.

Comment: Please give a few examples of multiple chart types (preferably also 3D charts) that are interactive, with animated graphics. Screenshots would be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

RGraph can be used under the GPL:

[www.rgraph.net](http://www.rgraph.net)

The latest release adds integration with Google Sheets.

PS I make it FYI

Comment: Please give a few examples of multiple chart types (preferably also 3D charts) that are interactive, with animated graphics. Screenshots would be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[LightningChart JS](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js/) allows building charting dashboards with WebGL acceleration, and might be an overkill solution for your needs, eventually? It's super-fast, and low-cost, and free for personal use. For commercial use we ask small fee.